# Java application uses DES to validate Linux users. DES is no longer a password encryption option in CentOS 8. What is a better method?

Tags: java, linux, rmi, des

I need to revise a Java program that validates Linux users.  It encrypts the typed password with DES crypt and sends it by Java RMI so the server program can compare it with /etc/shadow.

CentOS 8 no longer supports DES.  SSSD seems to be the default.

Is there a better method for validating a Linux user's name and password?

Comment: [JAAS-PAM](http://jaas-pam.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Both components run on different machines ?

Comment: Sometimes the same, sometimes remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JAAS_PAM suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch above (Thanks!).  I'm also using libpam4j and JNA.  If anyone asks, I'll look to see what I did.  I don't remember if those were required by JAAS_PAM.